# Remote Kubernetes development in Spyder (Python) with Okteto

Tags: kubernetes, visual-studio-code, spyder, okteto

For Visual Studio Code (VSC) it is possible to install the `Remote-Kubernetes`  extension which allows you to work directly with remote development environments, spinning them up, configuring them etc. More info [here](https://okteto.com/blog/remote-kubernetes-development/).

Is something similar possible for Spyder?

I am aware that a connection to a remote kernel can be made but this seems to require for the remote environment to already be running. Am looking for same functionality as the `okteto up`  command in VSC.

Comment: we don't have an integration to Spyder, but would something like what's described here (https://okteto.com/blog/remote-development-environments-with-pycharm/) help you out?